How to click an aria-label button with selenium
I'm trying to click a button using selenium and python, but I'm struggling with the right syntax. The css code looks as follows:
  <button aria-label="Weitere Jobs anzeigen" class="infinite-scroller__show-more-button" data-tracking-control-name="infinite-scroller_show-more">
      
            Weitere Jobs anzeigen
          
  </button>

The syntax I tried was
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button[aria-label='Weitere Jobs anzeigen']"))).click()

and
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[aria-label='Weitere Jobs anzeigen']"))).click()

but neither worked. Any help is appreciated!

Modified the HTML provided only to help indicate when the button has been clicked.  Otherwise the problem should be simulated to be identical, let me know if this helps.
Test Enviroment:

Python: 3.12.4
Selenium: 4.23.1
Web Driver: geckodriver-v0.35.0-linux-aarch64
OS: 6.9.12-3-MANJARO

Solution:
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".infinite-scroller__show-more-button"))).click()
Python:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

button_css_selector_path = ".infinite-scroller__show-more-button"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("<URL_OR_HTML_FILE>")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, button_css_selector_path))).click()



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button aria-label="Weitere Jobs anzeigen" class="infinite-scroller__show-more-button" data-tracking-control-name="infinite-scroller_show-more" onclick="alertUser()">    
        Weitere Jobs anzeigen
</button>
<script>
    const alertUser = () => alert("Button Has Been Clicked!")
</script>
</body>
</html>



The GIF was too large, shows everything I did check it out here
